# Is there any known connection between Star Trek: Federation and DISC Season three?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

It's an interesting thought.

About *Star Trek: Federation*,

> ...causes Vulcan, Bajor, and Betazed to leave in disgust at the corruption of the UFP, leaving it with only **twenty** systems under its control.

We see **six** stars (for planets) on the flag of the UFP in the [new trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46ec8WnBHes) for DISC Season three.

Also,

> The Ferengi become the dominant power in the galaxy, and make money by spreading the Bajoran religion and making Bajor into a major place of pilgrimage.

I suspect that something that important would have made it to the trailer.

Also, *Star Trek: Federation* was to be set in the year 3000. From DISC: "Such Sweet Sorrow, Part 2", we know that the crew of the *U.S.S. Discovery* traveled to year
2257+930=3187.

Despite all the information to the contrary above, perhaps there are still possible connections. Does anyone know if the writers plan on using some ideas from the undeveloped show? Any thoughts or comments?

Source for both quotes/information: [Star Trek: Federation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Federation)

Comment: my only thought is given how rights work, it is, imo, extremely unlikey that material written by somebody for a spec / undeveloped work, who is not involved in any current production or capacity would be leveraged in any way, lest a lawsuit also find it's way to the year 3000

Comment: Using those ideas would necessitate giving the ST:F creators partial creative credit. It is rather unlikely they've seen the proposal.